# FireBase - update field when using user authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, insert-update

I am stuck with FireBase right now. I have a function that I use to change the color of a star icon in my test app.
it works fine.
Now, I would like that when a user tap on the icon, it will update the value in the document in FireBase.

As I am starting from 4 weeks now to learn flutter, it is challenging. Many thanks for your help.

```
void _toggleFlagInbox() {
    setState(() {
      if (_isUrgentInboxTask == "true") {

        _isUrgentInboxTask = "false";

        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .doc("tasks")
            .collection("tasks")
            .where("task_Status", isEqualTo: task_Inbox)
            .get()
            .then((res) {
          res.docs.forEach((result) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("Users")
                .doc("tasks")
                .collection("tasks")
                .doc(result.id)
                .update({"important": "false"});
          });
        });


        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .collection('tasks')
            .docs
            .update({'important':"false"});

         

      } else {

        _isUrgentInboxTask = "true";
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have find. I copy what I am doing in case this help somebody else

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('inbox')
        .doc(document.id)
        .update({
        "important":"false"});
```